# I got RasperryPi stack exchange on the Jupiter Broadcasting TechSnap show, kinda :)

Tags: discussion

I recently started listening to this show [TechSnap](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/show/techsnap/) I found while spending countless of hours watching yuotube clips. It actually got me hooked as the questions are by people like you, or me and answered by Allan who is pretty clued up (and a massive BSD fan) in a fully technical non forgiving debates- Which I find enlightening. Just thought I would share it with you.

[Scroll down to feed back](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/26536/breaking-dkm-techsnap-81/) and there is a link 'FreeBSD on the Raspberry Pi?' with a link to a question on Pi SE.

Also Episode 81 at ~45 minutes in; they discuss the question briefly.

Comment: Nice :) That's awesome, keep up the advertising!